# How do I make my store private in React reflux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refluxjs

How do I enforce my store functions and model private. If my store is

```
var employeeActions = Reflux.createActions(['addEmployee']);

var empStore = Reflux.createstore({
listenables: [employeeActions],
model: {
          Total:0,
          employees:[]
}
onAddEmployee: function(employee){
   this.model.employees.push(employee);
}
});
```

Even though flux says Actions->Store. The current object structure doesnt stop a developer in the team from calling empStore.OnAddEmployee ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your store should be in a module, assuming you are using browserify or webpack or something similar and you `require` your modules. So any variable / object / function you declare in the module but don't include in the object sent to the `Reflux.createStore()` is private.

So something like this:

```js
var employeeActions = Reflux.createActions(['addEmployee']);

var model: {
          Total:0,
          employees:[]
}

var empStore = Reflux.createstore({
listenables: [employeeActions],

onAddEmployee: function(employee){
   model.employees.push(employee);
}
});
```

I would suggest keeping the `onAddEmployee` function on the object and rely on reflux to wire everything up if you're using the `listenables` mixin. Otherwise, just follow the examples on github: https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs#creating-data-stores and using the same principle, keep the function private, outside the object you are passing to the factory method.